# Check if XML coloumn in EF contains specific value

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework

I have a question about EF and XML coloumn in the EF Model.

I have a search page in my project with many fields. I intersect my values with code:

```
IQueryable<ServicesRegistration> query = null;

using (SelfServiceEntities context = new SelfServiceEntities())
{
    query = context.ServicesRegistrations.Include("BanStatusType").Where(c => c.AppID == "MyApp");
    if (filter.RequestStatus != null)
    {
        if (query == null)
        {
            query = context.ServicesRegistrations
                           .Include("BanStatusType")
                           .Where(c => c.BanStatusType.StatusID == filter.RequestStatus);
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.Where(c => c.BanStatusType.StatusID == filter.RequestStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

This work well for all simple types like string, int etc.

But when I try to do such operation on XML coloumn I get Exception:

> InnerException = {"Disallowed implicit conversion from data type xml
>   to data type nvarchar, table 'dbo.ServicesRegistrations', column
>   'MetadataXml'. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."}

My code is:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.SerialNumber))
{
    if (query == null)
    {
        query = context.ServicesRegistrations
                       .Include("BanStatusType").Where(c => c.MetadataXml.Contains(filter.SerialNumber));
    }
    else
    {
        query = query.Where(c => c.MetadataXml.Contains(filter.SerialNumber));
    }
}
```

I using Ef 3.5 and I know that there is some problem in implementation of XML data in it.

Is somebody solve such problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not allowed operation. The first problem is that EF doesn't support XML columns. It uses them as any other string column. So when you call Contains it converts the method to SQL equivalent for varchar columns. Obviously database doesn't allow this for XML columns without first converting them to varchar. And here we get to the initial problem. Because EF doesn't see XML column it cannot convert it in its query generator.